# opencv for python on mavericks

Tags: opencv, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I know its too soon, but ive upgraded to OSX mavericks and I'm unable to install opencv using Homebrew.

```
    ==> Installing dependencies for opencv: cmake, pkg-config, libpng
==> Installing opencv dependency: cmake
==> Downloading http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.12.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./bootstrap --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12 --system-libs --no-system-libarchive --datadir=/shar
==> make
==> make install
Warning: Could not link cmake. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link cmake'

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/ctest -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/bin/ctest
/usr/local/bin/cpack -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/bin/cpack
/usr/local/bin/cmakexbuild -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/bin/cmakexbuild
/usr/local/bin/cmake -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/bin/cmake
/usr/local/bin/ccmake -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/bin/ccmake
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ctest.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/ctest.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cpack.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/cpack.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cmakevars.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/cmakevars.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cmakeprops.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/cmakeprops.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cmakepolicies.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/cmakepolicies.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cmakemodules.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/cmakemodules.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cmakecompat.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/cmakecompat.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cmakecommands.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/cmakecommands.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cmake.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/cmake.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ccmake.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/man/man1/ccmake.1
/usr/local/share/doc/cmake -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/doc/cmake
/usr/local/share/cmake -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/cmake
/usr/local/share/aclocal/cmake.m4 -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/aclocal/cmake.m4
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12: 701 files, 36M, built in 4.5 minutes
==> Installing opencv dependency: pkg-config
==> Downloading http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.28.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28 --disable-host-tool --with-internal-glib --with-p
==> make
==> make check
==> make install
Warning: Could not link pkg-config. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link pkg-config'

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/pkg-config -> /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.27.1/bin/pkg-config
/usr/local/share/man/man1/pkg-config.1 -> /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.27.1/share/man/man1/pkg-config.1
/usr/local/share/doc/pkg-config -> /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.27.1/share/doc/pkg-config
/usr/local/share/aclocal/pkg.m4 -> /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.27.1/share/aclocal/pkg.m4
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28: 10 files, 604K, built in 60 seconds
==> Installing opencv dependency: libpng
==> Downloading http://downloads.sf.net/project/libpng/libpng15/older-releases/1.5.14/libpng-1.5.14.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.14
==> make install
Warning: Could not link libpng. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link libpng'

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/libpng15-config -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/bin/libpng15-config
/usr/local/bin/libpng-config -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/bin/libpng-config
/usr/local/include/pnglibconf.h -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/include/pnglibconf.h
/usr/local/include/pngconf.h -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/include/pngconf.h
/usr/local/include/png.h -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/include/png.h
/usr/local/include/libpng15 -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/include/libpng15
/usr/local/share/man/man5/png.5 -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/share/man/man5/png.5
/usr/local/share/man/man3/libpngpf.3 -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/share/man/man3/libpngpf.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3/libpng.3 -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/share/man/man3/libpng.3
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng15.pc -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/lib/pkgconfig/libpng15.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng.pc -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/lib/pkgconfig/libpng.pc
/usr/local/lib/libpng15.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/lib/libpng15.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpng15.a -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/lib/libpng15.a
/usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/lib/libpng.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpng.a -> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/lib/libpng.a
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.14: 15 files, 1.0M, built in 11 seconds
==> Installing opencv
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.6.1/opencv-2.4.6.1.ta
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAME
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
For non-homebrew python (2.x), you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:
  export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
Warning: Could not link opencv. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link opencv'

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/opencv_traincascade
/usr/local/bin/opencv_performance
/usr/local/bin/opencv_haartraining
/usr/local/bin/opencv_createsamples
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/videostab.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/stabilizer.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/optical_flow.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/motion_stabilizing.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/log.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/inpainting.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/global_motion.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/frame_source.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/fast_marching_inl.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/fast_marching.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/videostab/deblurring.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/video/video.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/video/tracking.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ts/ts_perf.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ts/ts_gtest.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ts/ts.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ts/gpu_test.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ts/gpu_perf.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/superres/superres.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/superres/optical_flow.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers_inl.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/util_inl.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/util.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/seam_finders.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/motion_estimators.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/matchers.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/exposure_compensate.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/camera.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/autocalib.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/photo/photo_c.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/photo/photo.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ocl/matrix_operations.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/ocl.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/legacy/streams.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/legacy/blobtrack.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/stream_accessor.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpumat.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/devmem2d.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/warp_shuffle.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/warp_reduce.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/warp.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/vec_traits.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/vec_math.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/vec_distance.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/utility.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/type_traits.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/transform.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/static_check.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/simd_functions.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/scan.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/saturate_cast.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/reduce.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/limits.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/functional.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/funcattrib.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/filters.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/emulation.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/dynamic_smem.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/vec_distance_detail.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/type_traits_detail.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/transform_detail.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/reduce_key_val.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/reduce.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/color_detail.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/datamov_utils.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/common.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/color.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/border_interpolate.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/device/block.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/timer.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/simplex_downhill.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/saving.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/sampling.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/result_set.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/random.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/params.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/object_factory.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/nn_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/matrix.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/logger.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/linear_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kmeans_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_single_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/index_testing.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/hierarchical_clustering_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/heap.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/ground_truth.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/general.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dynamic_bitset.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dummy.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dist.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/defines.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/config.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/composite_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/autotuned_index.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/any.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/allocator.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/wimage.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opengl_interop_deprecated.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/opengl_interop.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/internal.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/gpumat.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/devmem2d.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cuda_devptrs.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/contrib/retina.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/contrib/openfabmap.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/contrib/hybridtracker.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/contrib/detection_based_tracker.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv/ml.h
/usr/local/include/opencv/highgui.h
/usr/local/include/opencv/cxmisc.h
/usr/local/include/opencv/cxeigen.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv/cxcore.h
/usr/local/include/opencv/cvwimage.h
/usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.h
/usr/local/include/opencv/cv.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_silverware.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_profileface.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_smile.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_profileface.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_rightear.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_lowerbody.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_fullbody.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.4.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.5.dylib
Error: undefined method `unlink' for nil:NilClass
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:537:in `record_cxx_stdlib'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:389:in `finish'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:90:in `install_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:31:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:29:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:29:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:95:in `send'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:95
```

Can someone help with this?

UPDATE: after linking the files manually and trying to install opencv again I get this:

```
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.6.1/opencv-2.4.6.1.ta
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/opencv-2.4.6.1.tar.gz
==> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAME
==> make
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/c++     -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   -compatibility_version 2.4.0 -current_version 2.4.6 -o ../../lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.6.dylib -install_name /tmp/opencv-4ERH/opencv-2.4.6.1/macbuild/lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.dylib CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/autocalib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/blenders.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/camera.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/exposure_compensate.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/matchers.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/motion_estimators.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/precomp.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/seam_finders.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/stitcher.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/util.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_stitching.dir/src/warpers.cpp.o ../../lib/libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_flann.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_features2d.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_video.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_photo.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_ml.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_legacy.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_gpu.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_ocl.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_nonfree.2.4.6.dylib -framework OpenCL ../../lib/libopencv_gpu.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_photo.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_legacy.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_ml.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_ocl.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_features2d.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_flann.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_video.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib /usr/lib/libz.dylib -framework OpenCL 
cd /tmp/opencv-4ERH/opencv-2.4.6.1/macbuild/modules/stitching && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12/bin/cmake -E cmake_symlink_library ../../lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.6.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.dylib ../../lib/libopencv_stitching.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /tmp/opencv-4ERH/opencv-2.4.6.1/macbuild/CMakeFiles  92
[100%] Built target opencv_stitching
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I'm having same problem too

Comment: I think OpenCV was not ready for OSX 10.9 and neither was homebrew and I need OpenCV for my projects. damn!

Comment: the fact is that no compiler error is shown, so it's not clear what's going wrong

Comment: ive opened the issue here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/402

Comment: Same error- did you get this working?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to install opencv on a fresh install of mavericks by installing the command line tools provided by apple (either via Xcode or via the [developer's site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads)), using the [cmake installer](http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.12-Darwin64-universal.dmg) to install cmake, then grabbing the [opencv2.4.3 source](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/2.4.3.tar.gz) and running the following:

```
tar -xf opencv-2.4.3.tar.gz
cd opencv-2.4.3
echo "#define GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE 1" | cat > temp1
cat modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts_gtest.h > temp2
cat temp1 temp2 > modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts_gtest.h
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -Wno-dev
make -j8 && sudo make install
```

Comment: tried it. gives me this error: /Users/abhishek/Documents/opencv-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:81:12: fatal error: 
      'libavformat/avformat.h' file not found
  #include <libavformat/avformat.h>

Comment: I had a similar problem. I'll install ffmpeg and give it a go again tomorrow.